# addAttributeToFilter for Multislect Attribute Update Query Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, mageplaza, addattributetofilter

I have Multiselect product attribute and i want to filter product by that attribute.

Currently i am using below code,

```
$productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
                    array(
                        array('attribute'=> 'fabriccolor','finset' => 16),
                        array('attribute'=> 'fabriccolor','finset' => 17),                  
                    )
                );
echo $productCollection->getSelect();
```

The query i get like

> SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`,
> `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
> `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL,
> LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price),
> price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`,
> `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`,
> `at_fabriccolor`.`value` AS `fabriccolor` FROM
> `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN
> `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON
> cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND
> cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id=3 INNER JOIN
> `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON
> price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id
> = 0 AND price_index.website_id = '1' INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_fabriccolor` ON
> (`at_fabriccolor`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
> (`at_fabriccolor`.`attribute_id` = '155') AND
> (`at_fabriccolor`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE ((FIND_IN_SET(16,
> at_fabriccolor.value)) OR (FIND_IN_SET(17, at_fabriccolor.value)))

The products i get which has fabriccolor value 16 or 17. Please check this screenshot,

[image]

But i want to filter the product which have both fabriccolor value 16 and 17 by code.
I want to update the query from
WHERE ((FIND_IN_SET(16,> at_fabriccolor.value)) **OR** (FIND_IN_SET(17, at_fabriccolor.value))) to WHERE ((FIND_IN_SET(16,> at_fabriccolor.value)) **AND** (FIND_IN_SET(17, at_fabriccolor.value))).

If i put the AND in the query then it gives me correct products which i want. Please check below screenshot,

[image]

So, how can i filter products by AND insted of OR.
Please help me if you have any solution.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: For "AND", just repeat the $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter() for each value or pass value as array in single stament.

Answer (score 0):

How about you change your code like this:

```php
$productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('fabricolor', ['finset' => [16,17]]);
echo $productCollection->getSelect();
```

or

```php
$productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('fabricolor', ['finset' => 16]);
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('fabricolor', ['finset' => 17]);
echo $productCollection->getSelect();
```

Comment: updated my answer with another way to try

Answer (score 0):

I have the code below working on my local:

```
public function afterGetProductCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
    ) {
        $values = [117,136,124,125,127];
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $filters[] = [
                'attribute'=> 'style_general',
                'finset' => $value
            ];
        }

        $collection->addAttributeToFilter($filters);

        return $collection;
    }
```

I believe with your snippet, it would look like:

```
$productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
        $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
            ['attribute'=> 'fabricolor', 'finset' => 16],
            ['attribute'=> 'fabricolor', 'finset' => 17],
        );
```

Now, I appreciate this is (very) similar to what you have. So my next question may be to see what is the full details (in the eav-attribute) of your attribute?